# QProcess execution time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qprocess

I would like to measure execution time of a `QProcess` object.

Is there an internal attribute, method or object in PySide for execution time measurements?

The current approach is to measure it from the outside using time.time().

Example code:

```
from PySide import QtCore
import time

p = QtCore.QProcess()
start_time = time.time()
p.start('ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul')
p.waitForFinished(-1)
end_time = time.time() - start_time

print(end_time)
```

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the current approach.

Comment: Have you tried `timeit`?

Comment: @busfault Not sure measuring the time is measuring the execution time...

Comment: @Trilarion The OP's code is measuring the time...

Comment: @Nir What exactly do you want to measure? the `QProcess`, the `ping` do you want Execution time, the time executing on the processor, or the wall clock time it took to run?

Comment: I want to measure the time it total time it took for the process to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is as follows. This uses the systems `time` command to get the time of execution.

```
from PySide import QtCore
import time

p = QtCore.QProcess()
p.start('time -p ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul')
p.waitForFinished(-1)
stdOut = p.readAllStandardOutput()
print(stdOut)
#TODO you will have to regex the stdOut to get the values you want.
```

Here is another approach:

```
from PySide import QtCore
import time

timer = QtCore.QTime()


def handle_proc_stop(*vargs):
    procTime = timer.elapsed()
    print("Process took {} miliseconds".format(procTime))

p = QtCore.QProcess()
p.started.connect(timer.start)
p.finished.connect(handle_proc_stop)
p.start('ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul')
p.waitForFinished(-1)
```

Comment: I liked the second approach. Thanks!